# is `dd` an entire partition necessary in case of file loss?

Tags: partition, backup, dd

Usually when having file loss problem with a filesystem in a partition, the first step is to `dd` the entire partition.

When the use percentage of the partition by files is   less than 50%, `dd` the whole partition seems to waste backup space.

Is `dd` the entire partition necessary? If not, how can I `dd` only the necessary part?

Is there some tool which can show the min and max of the address range of the sectors/blocks occupied by the files in a partition? Maybe that can help to narrow the part to be `dd`ed?

Thanks.

Comment: The trick is, How do identify the "necessary part"?  How do you know where on the partition the file lived?

Answer (score 0):

Where does this "usually" in your assertion come from? The first step could be anything. Restore from backup, revert to version in revision control repo, even undelete with some filesystems. Your "usually" assumes a partion byte by byte copy exists.

But to answer the question, a compressed copy of the partition can be stored, and dd can be limited with the count command. If the partition was zero'd at any time, the compressed file can be quite economical.

But a better solution would be to use a backup system using block de-duplication.